# made a loop to check all inputArrs but it's checking just the first one

Tags: javascript, loops, foreach

I made a loop to check all `inputArr` elements, but it checks just the first one and if it is true it does not check the other ones and returns true. I need to check all of them and if any of them is false want to get an error message.  I tried with forEach as well but still does not work

here is my code

```
btn.addEventListener('click', function () {
    let isValid = checkIfValid([firstName, surname, email, mobileNumber])
    let userInfo = generateInputs(firstName.value, surname.value, email.value, mobileNumber.value);
    if (isValid) {
     console.log('all checked')
    } else {
     console.log('you need to fill all fields')
    }
})


function checkIfValid(inputArr) {
    for (let i = 0; i < inputArr.length; i++) {
        if (inputArr[i].value === '') {
            return false
        } else {
            console.log(inputArr[i].value)
            return true
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `return` will exit the loop, same as `break`

Answer (score 1):

Your `return true` statement stops the for loop.

This will work, returning false on the first invalid item, else true:

```js
function checkIfValid(inputArr) {
    for (let i = 0; i < inputArr.length; i++) {
        if (inputArr[i].value === '') {
            return false
        } else {
            console.log(inputArr[i].value)
        }
    }
    return true
}
```

**Modern alternative**:

You can use `Array.prototype.every()` to simplify the code:

```js
function checkIfValid(inputArr) {
    return inputArr.every(el => el.value !== '');
}
```